# Why does matplotlib's timer speed up when PyQt button is pressed?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have a small GUI I made with PyQt5 that basically consists of a real-time plot and two buttons to stop and resume. I want to update the plot every `measure_interval` miliseconds. In my script, I set it to 1000 (1 second). The program starts working properly, but when I press the "Stop" button and then resume with "Start", the timer appears to accelerate even though its time interval is not changed. In fact, whenever I press the "Start" button, the plotting speeds up (even without previously stopping it). So I believe the mistake is there, even though I can't spot it. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        global measure_interval
        super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()
        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)
        # Canvas
        dynamic_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(10, 10)))
        self._dynamic_ax = dynamic_canvas.figure.subplots()
        self._timer = dynamic_canvas.new_timer(measure_interval, [(self._update_window, (), {})])
        self._timer.start()
        # Buttons
        button_stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Stop', self)
        button_stop.clicked.connect(self._timer.stop)
        button_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start', self)
        button_start.clicked.connect(self._timer.start)
        # Layout
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self._main)
        layout.addWidget(dynamic_canvas)
        layout.addWidget(button_stop)
        layout.addWidget(button_start)

    def _update_window(self):
        global x, y, win_size, count_iter
        # Update variables
        x.append(x[count_iter] + 0.01)
        y.append(np.random.random())
        idx_inf = max([count_iter-win_size, 0])
        count_iter += 1
        # Plot
        self._dynamic_ax.clear()
        self._dynamic_ax.plot(x[idx_inf:count_iter], y[idx_inf:count_iter],'-o', color='b')
        self._dynamic_ax.figure.canvas.draw()
#%%
if __name__ == "__main__":
    measure_interval = 1000 # milisegs
    win_size = 100 # maximum window size (samples)
    y = [np.random.random()]
    x = [0]
    count_iter = 0
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app = ApplicationWindow()
    app.show()
    qapp.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer interval gets reset to `0` when pressing the start button.
This is due to the fact that the `.start()` function takes an argument `interval` which is meant to set the interval for the timer.

However, when using the `start()` directly as a callback for the `clicked` signal of the button, some status `False` will be supplied to the callback. So essentially when pressing the button you call `start(False)`. This is the same as `start(0)` in python and hence the interval is set to `0`.

To avoid this, you may use a lambda function and make sure `start()` is called without argument, in which case it will remember the initally set intervall and use it.

```
button_start.clicked.connect(lambda : self._timer.start())
```

Comment: Nice and simple workaround, thanks. I'm still trying to find out why the resetting happens... Let me know if you find out anything about it!

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks!